# Fix " error TS2339: Property does not exist on type 'string'." in Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-components

I created a both parent and child components in Angular(v 16) and tried to pass data from the child to parent component using the "ViewChild" decorator and "AfterViewInit" method.I did everything as shown in the tutorial but I am unable to retrieve the data of the child component. I am ending up with the following error
"error TS2339: Property 'childData' does not exist on type 'string'."
I checked out almost everything, please show me a way or mistake I am doing.
I am attaching my code below.

This is the child component
[image: Child]

This is the parent component
[image: Parent]

Comment: [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/17447)

Comment: Angular components can define custom events by assigning a property to a new  [`EventEmitter`](https://angular.io/api/core/EventEmitter) and adding the [`@Output`](https://angular.io/api/core/Output) decorator. 

Example: https://angular.dev/guide/components/outputs

Answer (score 0):

In the MainComponent, you are declaring `childInt` without any type
`@ViewCild(SubmainComponent) childInt`.

In the constructor of MainComponent you are initializing `childInt` like this : `this.childInt='';` therefore typescript consider `childInt` to be of type string which cause your error message